# DistributionNotFound error with pydev on external lib

Tags: python, pydev

I am trying to do my first python program using an external [Ckan library](https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi#ckanapi-python-module). I added the library and it seems to be working because the command `import ckanap` does not give me no errors. BUT when i try to run the program, i get this error

> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: ckanapi

the full error message (if needed) is this

```
Finding files... done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ilias/Programming/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/pydev_runfiles.py", line 468, in __get_module_from_str
    mod = __import__(modname)
  File "/home/ilias/EclipseWorkspace/PythonFirst/root/nested/example.py", line 14, in <module>
    import ckanapi
  File "/home/ilias/Downloads/ckanapi-master/ckanapi/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ckanapi.remoteckan import RemoteCKAN
  File "/home/ilias/Downloads/ckanapi-master/ckanapi/remoteckan.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ckanapi.version import __version__
  File "/home/ilias/Downloads/ckanapi-master/ckanapi/version.py", line 3, in <module>
    __version__ = pkg_resources.require("ckanapi")[0].version
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 725, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: ckanapi
ERROR: Module: example could not be imported (file: /home/ilias/EclipseWorkspace/PythonFirst/root/nested/example.py).
Importing test modules ... done.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
OK
```

I have search the internet about it, but the error is not much helpfull, let alone that i am complete newbie to python.

by the way, i get this error even with no commands at all, just with the import statement

*Edit*
Output of command`python -c "import sys ; print( '\n'.join(sorted(sys.path)))"`

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an installation issue with ckanapi...

It seems it has many dependencies: https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi/blob/master/requirements.txt

How did you install it? Have you tried pip install ckanapi?

Comment: I didnt install it, i download it and add it as external directory/zip file in pyDev. isnt that the right way?

Comment: Well, if it didn't have any dependency that'd suffice, but as it doesn't, the best way is probably using `pip install ckanapi` so that dependencies are also installed.

Comment: ok,  i did that and the terminal returned no errors, now what? i run eclipse/pydev but got the same error. should i restart the computer?

Comment: Please check if your PYTHONPATH is the same on both cases (i.e.: do `import sys;print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path)))` and compare the results).

Comment: this command gave me an error so i used this`python -c "import sys ; print '\n'.join(sorted(sys.path))"` check the edited question for output. i am not sure what this list is

Comment: Well, instead of executing in the command line, create a script with that and run it from within PyDev to know which configuration is being used inside PyDev.

Comment: Thanks for all the info and help friend, but its way too complicated, the whole python thing. I dont have the time to spend on learning something new just to solve my problem. I will try and do this using Java. Thanks again. (Should I delete this question now?)